# Decrease values by a range of percentage selected randomly

Tags: python, pandas

I have the values of the electricity consumption of 36 households (df), I would like to modify only the values of the peak hours (from 17:00 to 23:00). I would like to do this by multiplying them by a factor, however, I want this factor to change randomly from 8% to 12%.

I removed the time (HH:MM:SS) from the datetime column with the following function:

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.strftime ('%H:%M:%S')
```

Then I compare the values of the column df['Time'] to those of the peak hours with the following function

```
df.loc[(df['Time'] == '17:00:00') | (df['Time'] == '17:30:00') | (df['Time'] == '18:00:00') | (df['Time'] == '18:30:00') | (df['Time'] == '19:00:00') | (df['Time'] == '19:30:00') | (df['Time'] == '20:00:00') | (df['Time'] == '20:30:00') | (df['Time'] == '21:00:00') | (df['Time'] == '21:30:00') | (df['Time'] == '22:00:00') | (df['Time'] == '22:30:00') | (df['Time'] == '23:00:00') , 'Response KWH/hh (per half hour) '] *= 0.9
```

But I have the following question:

1. How can I change the factor 0.9 for a factor randomly selected from the range 0.08 to 0.12 instead of fixed factor? so each of the 30 minutes samples is multiply by a different factor that falls between 0.08 to 0.12

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case an example DataFrame would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea should be as follows:

```
rand_nums = np.random.rand(shape)*(0.12-0.08) + 0.08
```

This gives you random values between 0.08 and 0.12.

Then you can multiply this by your array of times, converted into seconds.

Comment: I do not need to multiply this by the time, I need to multiply the electricity consumption by a factor between 0.08-0.12, but I want this factor to change randomly between that range (0.08-0.12). Would it be enough with rand_nums = np.random.rand(shape)*(0.12-0.08)?

Comment: The formula I gave will give random numbers between 0.08 and 0.12. The formula you wrote in your comment will give random numbers between 0.00 and 0.04. That's why I add on the 0.08.

Comment: Thank you, however, I think the variable (shape) is undefined, how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes that was a placeholder. You want it to match the array of values you are multiplying. So if you have a column vector with 13 electricity readings (`shape` = (13,1)) you'll want the same shape for your random number array.

Comment: I am working with pandas  not numpy, so the shape is not specific, it depends on the values that fall between the time range (17:00 to 23:00), so unfortunately rand_nums = np.random.rand(shape)*(0.12-0.08) + 0.08 is not working

Comment: You can get the dimensionality of a pandas dataframe using `df.shape`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html

Comment: I understand, but my concern is as I said I am working with pandas and not numpy, for that reason I also got the error 'Data must be 1-dimensional'

Comment: You can get one-dimensional random numbers by doing `np.random.rand(13)`.

Comment: There is nothing incompatible about using pandas and numpy together.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now, however, I have one more and last question, I do not know the size of vector (in this example I do because I cut the data), because I do not know how many values fall on the data range I used to filter, so I could set the size of np.random(13) according to my condition, or in other words, how can I set the number 13 in your example variable?

Comment: You could break your code down into a few lines. First do your query to get your dataframe, then get the shape of the output, then use that to generate n random numbers.

Comment: PS Feel free to upvote and accept if this answered your question.